# Django REST Framework: Alternate Field Names

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to create a universal model which will take in a product name, its options, and the price. Here is the example json I want to send.

```
{
    "product": "jacket",
    "options": {
       "color": ["purple"],
       "size": ["s", "m", "l"],
       (I want the ability to add unlimited strings here)
       },
   "price": 234
}
```

My problem is that I need to generalize the color and sizes.  IE, options should contain a `CharField`, `option_name`, which could be repeated over and over with different option names with unique values. Is there a way to do this using more data tables or a built in Django REST functionality?

Comment: If you want a field to contain arbitrarily nested data structures, you can use a JSONField. This is only available with the postgresql database backend, though. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/contrib/postgres/fields/#jsonfield

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you should consider making `Option` a separate table and have it related to your `Product` table via a foreign key. In other words, a product can have many options.

```
class Product(models.Model):
    product_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    price = models.IntegerField()

class Option(models.Model):
    color = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    size = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product) # an option is associated with a product
```

So now you don't need a "universal model". `Product` is your main model. You could then define your serializers like the following:

```
class OptionSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Option
        fields = ('color', 'size')

class ProductSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    options = OptionSerializer(source='option_set', many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = ('product_name', 'price', 'options')
```

Now when you retrieve a `Product` instance, it has the following information:

```
var product = {
  "product_name": "jacket",
  "price": 123,
  "options": [
    {"color": "purple", "size": "l"},
    {"color": "red", "size": "s"},
    ...
  ] 
}
```

This does change your planned json, but has all the information for the possible options of a product.